# How to smooth mostly vertical lines in R?

Tags: r, smoothing

I need to smooth lines with many different y values for single x. For example

```
x <- c(73.8675, 74.2025, 74.2025, 74.5375, 74.5375, 74.5375, 74.5375, 
74.5375, 74.5375, 74.5375)

y <- c(21.9425, 22.2775, 22.6125, 22.9475, 23.2825, 23.6175, 23.9525, 
24.2875, 24.6225, 24.9575)

plot(x, y)
```

[image]

I tried

```
smooth.spline(x, y)
loess(y ~ x)
```

but it does not work properly in my case. What algorithms are suitable for this task?

Comment: Are you looking for one line through each set of points? `abline(v = unique(x))` will generate a vertical line for each x-value that will pass through the points, but I'm not certain if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I need single smooth line in result

Comment: you could use     scatter.smooth(x,y)

Comment: I need values not plot